# Create live stream event using brightcove api

Tags: php, api, http-live-streaming, brightcove

I have a question is there any way we can make a live streaming event using bright-cove API and store that live streamed video to bright-cove server once we finish our event as I have searched a lot but all efforts goes in vain a small hint would be enough but if some one could refer me to any link would be more appreciated Thank you in advance.

Comment: There's a Live video offering from Brightcove that would handle this. If you're managing the video streams externally you could likely use a Remote Video in the CMS API to serve as a basic reference to those streams and update the associated assets accordingly.